# one OrbitControls with two scenes

Tags: three.js

I want to sync the mouse control of two .dae files (in two scenes side-by-side) with OrbitControls. I can control any one object individually with any one of my scenes but any attempt to control both objects in sync fails.
It seems like I can only have one OrbitControls instance. Any one of the following 'controls#' lines works on its own but as soon as I have both, only the first one is operative:
**controls1 = new OrbitControls( camera1, renderer1.domElement );
controls2 = new OrbitControls( camera2, renderer2.domElement );**

I am a chemistry prof, not a programmer.Any help is gratefully appreciated. Thanks!

````
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>GD - 2 mols</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3> VB orbital visualizer: 2 molecules</h3>
        

<div id="molcontainer1"></div>
<div id="molcontainer2"></div>
        
    <!-- Remove this when import maps will be widely supported -->
        <script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>

        <script type="importmap">
            {
                "imports": {
                    "three": "../three/build/three.module.js"
                }
            }
        </script>

        <script type="module">

            import * as THREE from 'three';
            import { ColladaLoader } from '../three/examples/jsm/loaders/ColladaLoader.js';         
            import { OrbitControls } from '../three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

            let molcontainer1, molcontainer2, camera1, camera2, scene1, scene2, renderer1, renderer2, mol1, mol2;

            init();
            //animate();

            function init() {

                molcontainer1 = document.getElementById( 'molcontainer1' );
                molcontainer2 = document.getElementById( 'molcontainer2' );
                
                //scene, camera, lighting, etc
                
                scene1 = new THREE.Scene();
                scene1.background = new THREE.Color( 0xbbffff ); 
                scene2 = new THREE.Scene();
                scene2.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffcccc );
                
                camera1 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 2000 );
                camera1.position.set( 0.4, 0.4, 0.4 );
                camera1.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );
                camera2 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 2000 );
                camera2.position.set( 0.4, 0.4, 0.4 );
                camera2.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

                const ambientLight1 = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 1 );  // was 0xcccccc
                scene1.add( ambientLight1 ); 
                const ambientLight2 = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 1 );  // was 0xcccccc
                scene2.add( ambientLight2 );

                const directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
                directionalLight1.position.set( 1, 1, 1 ).normalize();
                scene1.add( directionalLight1 );
                const directionalLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
                directionalLight2.position.set( 1, 1, 1 ).normalize();
                scene2.add( directionalLight2 );

                renderer1 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer1.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
                renderer1.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer1.setSize( window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/2 );
                molcontainer1.appendChild( renderer1.domElement );
                
                renderer2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer2.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
                renderer2.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer2.setSize( window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/2 );
                molcontainer2.appendChild( renderer2.domElement );
                
                // loading manager

                const loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager( function () {
                    
                    scene1.add( mol1 );
                    scene2.add( mol2 );

                } );

                // assign collada .dae file

                const loader1 = new ColladaLoader( loadingManager );
                loader1.load( './models/molecule.dae', function ( collada ) {

                    mol1 = collada.scene;
                    animate();
                    render();
                } );

                const loader2 = new ColladaLoader( loadingManager );
                loader2.load( './models/CH2CHO.dae', function ( collada ) {

                    mol2 = collada.scene;
                    animate();
                    render();
                } );
                
                // 3d mouse controls    
                
                controls1 = new OrbitControls( camera1, renderer1.domElement );
                controls2 = new OrbitControls( camera2, renderer2.domElement );
                controls1.addEventListener( 'change', render );
                controls2.addEventListener( 'change', render );
                controls1.target.set( 0, 0, 0 ); 
                controls2.target.set( 0, 0, 0 ); 
                //controls.update();
                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize ); 
            }
        

            function animate() {
              
                requestAnimationFrame( animate);
                
                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );    // just added this   
                render();
            }

            
            function onWindowResize() {

                camera1.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera1.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer1.setSize( window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/2 );
                camera2.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera2.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer2.setSize( window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/2 );
                
                render();
            }
            
            function render() {

                renderer1.render( scene1, camera1 );
                renderer2.render( scene2, camera2 );
                //controls.update();
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 1):

You actually only need one camera and one `OrbitControls` to drive the two renderers and `Scene`s.  The reason for this is that neither is intrinsically tied to the renderer or the `Scene`; the camera basically just tracks a group of variables that, on each frame, allow the renderer to compute its projection, and the `OrbitControls` only cares about the user's interaction with (a defined portion of) the page and the camera whose values it needs to mutate.  (Note, as well, that neither a camera nor an `OrbitControls` takes any reference to a renderer or `Scene` when you initialize it, and most examples you see don't use `Scene.Add()` to add the camera to the scene graph.)

So, your code needs the following modifications.

First, wrap your `molcontainer*` `div`s inside of another `div`, and give it an ID of, say, `molwrapper`.  This wrapper `div` will define the area on the page (comprising the two scenes) that will receive the user interaction for the `OrbitControls`.  Use `document.getElementById()` to store a reference to `molwrapper`.

Next, remove all references to `camera2` and rename `camera1` to `camera`, and do the same with `controls2` and `controls1`.

Finally, initialize `controls` (which used to be `controls1`) by passing it references to `camera` (which used to be `camera1`) and `molwrapper`.

I've posted a working [example](https://codepen.io/pnichols04/full/VwQjRjg) on CodePen.

Comment: Hi Phil, Thank you so much for the help! I was able to make it work as you suggested. I noted that rotating objects sometimes gets stuck in gimbal lock. Are my `controls.update()` not set properly (I did uncomment it on my original code)?